# how to add arrays inside an array in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am trying to create a list of arrays inside of arrays to pass it to a data table, but not sure how to populate the data.

This is what I want to print out.

```
data.rows = [
  ['name', 'age', 'user name', 'email', 'mobile'],
  ['name', 'age', 'user name', 'email', 'mobile'],
  ['name', 'age', 'user name', 'email', 'mobile'],
  ['name', 'age', 'user name', 'email', 'mobile'],
];
```

When i transformed the data, i am getting output like this.

```
data.rows = [
  0:['name', 'age', 'user name', 'email', 'mobile'],
  1:['name', 'age', 'user name', 'email', 'mobile']
]
```

Can someone pls help with this.

Comment: Your output seems to be correct. Could you please add the input and the code you have tried so far?

Comment: how are you transforming the data? and can you update you're question with desired output

Comment: your output is incorrect. its not valid javascript. what did your console actually show?

Comment: I am getting the output but with keys , i am trying to get output like first one.

data.rows = [
  ['name', 'age', 'user name', 'email', 'mobile'],
  ['name', 'age', 'user name', 'email', 'mobile'],
  ['name', 'age', 'user name', 'email', 'mobile'],
  ['name', 'age', 'user name', 'email', 'mobile'],
];

Comment: @MulliganᛜReinstatingMonica i did not understand why it's not a valid question, i need to construct the array of arrays like i mentioned in the question because the data table i am using is taking only in that format.

Comment: can you clarify how you transformed your data?

Comment: @MulliganᛜReinstatingMonica
input:

[{name:'john',age:30},{name:'steven',age:40}]

expected output

[
  [john,30],
  [steven,40]
]

the output i am getting

[
 0:[john,30],
 1:[steven,40]
]

i used object.keys and object.values to get that output.

Comment: Here is the js fiddle
https://jsfiddle.net/venkateshchekuri/fx5htopz/1/

Answer (score 0):

This is how you can add arrays inside an array

```
data.rows = [];
data.rows.push(['name', 'age', 'user name', 'email', 'mobile']);
data.rows.push(['name', 'age', 'user name', 'email', 'mobile']);
data.rows.push(['name', 'age', 'user name', 'email', 'mobile']);
data.rows.push(['name', 'age', 'user name', 'email', 'mobile']);
```

Comment: it won't give the output i am expecting.

Answer (score 0):

your output is exactly what you want. Both the same.

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this

```
let data = ['name', 'age', 'user name', 'email', 'mobile'];
let arr =[];
for(let i=0; i<5; i++)
  arr.push(data)

console.log(arr)
```

result

```
[
  [ 'name', 'age', 'user name', 'email', 'mobile' ],
  [ 'name', 'age', 'user name', 'email', 'mobile' ],
  [ 'name', 'age', 'user name', 'email', 'mobile' ],
  [ 'name', 'age', 'user name', 'email', 'mobile' ],
  [ 'name', 'age', 'user name', 'email', 'mobile' ]
]
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, my bad. it was some other error in the datatable. the way i transformed the data worked.
Here is the JSFiddle

```
jsfiddle.net/venkateshchekuri/fx5htopz/1
```